# Find the horizontal asymptotes of $f(x) = \sqrt{​x^2+​x+​2} - \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}$ with Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

$f(x) = \sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} - \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}$

I dont understand how to use Limits to find asymptotes, I tried working on it by dividing everything by x and result was 0. I double checked with a graphing calculator to find that the answer is $y = 3/2 , y =-3/2$

Comment: can you verify the edit that I have made ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I did some more in the title

Comment: @A.Γ.I think that is where the sqrt are intended to be too ... Would be nice if BoyStruggles could verify this ?

Comment: Hint: try the following $$\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$

Comment: yeah sorry for the bad format, you formatted right

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can't just divide by $x$, because that changes the expression. You want to modify the expression in ways that don't change it.

A hint for how to proceed: Try multiplying and dividing by the conjugate. (Recall: the conjugate of $\sqrt a - \sqrt b$ is $\sqrt a + \sqrt b$.) This operation won't change the expression, because you're effectively multiplying by 1.

Comment: I prepared a full answer along these lines, but I like the idea of a hint, as you’ve given, better. If OP would like, I can post my full answer.

Comment: I think after the hint I got the answer! But another perspective on the question wouldn't hurt!

Answer (score 2):

More generally, for $x\not=0$,
$$\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​bx+​c} - \sqrt{​x^{​2}+dx+​e}=|x|\left(\sqrt{​1+\frac{b}{x}+​o(1/x)} - \sqrt{​1+​\frac{d}{x}+o(1/x)}\right)\\
=|x|\left(1+\frac{b}{2x} - ​1-\frac{d}{2x}+o(1/x)\right)=\frac{(b-d)|x|}{2x}+o(1)$$
where we used the fact that $\sqrt{1+t+o(t)}=1+\frac{t}{2}+o(t)$ as $t\to 0$.

Hence the asymptotes are $y=\frac{b-d}{2}$ ($x\to +\infty$), and $y=\frac{d-b}{2}$ ($x\to -\infty$).

Answer (score 0):

Must be clear something that my student find hard to understand

$\sqrt{x^2}$ is NOT $x$, because $x$ can be negative while $\sqrt{x^2}$ is larger than or equal to zero for any $x$.

Indeed $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for $x\ge 0$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ for $x<0$ so the result is positive for any $x$

To be simpler $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

When we look for the limit as $x\to +\infty$ of $f(x)$ we get
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \left(\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} - \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}\right)$$
which is not zero. $\infty-\infty$ is NOT zero. It can be zero, $\infty$ or any  real number.

It's a form of indetermination. The standard way to solve it is to try to convert it in a fraction, like this
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{\left(\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} - \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}\right)\left(\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} + \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}\right)}{\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} + \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}}$$
Numerator is like $(a-b)(a+b)$ and gives $a^2-b^2$ so we get rid of the radicals
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{​x^{​2}+​x+​2 - (x^{​2}-2​x+​5)}{\sqrt{​x^{​2}+​x+​2} + \sqrt{​x^{​2}-2​x+​5}}$$
In the denominator inside the radicals we can collect $x^2$ to bring them out after
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{​x^{​2}+​x+​2 - x^{​2}+2​x-​5}{\sqrt{​x^{​2}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}\right)} + \sqrt{​x^{​2}\left(1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}\right)}}$$
Now as $x\to+\infty$ means that $x>0$ we extract $x$ from the radical in the denominator
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{​3​x-​3}{x\sqrt{​1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} + x\sqrt{​1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}}\quad(*)$$
Now we can collect $x$ in the numerator and the denominator
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{​x\left(3​-​\frac{3}{x}\right)}{x\left(\sqrt{​1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} + \sqrt{​1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}\right)}$$
and finally simplify $x$
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, \frac{​3​-​\frac{3}{x}}{\sqrt{​1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} + \sqrt{​1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}}$$
Now $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}\to 0$ so the limit is
$$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to +\infty } \, f(x)=\frac{3}{2}}$$
$$.$$
When dealing with $x\to-\infty$ the step marked with $(*)$ changes in this way
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty } \, \frac{​3​x-​3}{-x\sqrt{​1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} -x\sqrt{​1-\frac{2}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2}}}$$
because $x$ is negative and according to what I said above $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $-x$

The steps go on exactly in the same way as above until you get
$$\color{red}{\lim_{x\to -\infty } \, f(x)=-\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$.$$
Hope this can be useful...

$$.$$
Edit

I added a picture which shows very well that is wrong to say that an asymptote is a line that never intersect the curve, because they CAN intersect, even infinite times...

[image]